# WCF IDispatchMessageInspector How to fix incoming xml?

Tags: c#, wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

In the WCF service, I have implemented the `IDispatchMessageInspector` interface.
In the `AfterReceiveRequest` method `ref Message request` - the error "when reading the body: System.Xml.XmlException" comes. This error occurs due to an error in the XML in the request.I can't influence the request.

```
<data xsi:type="xsd:string"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <someRequest>
    <Number>Test</Number>
    <Date>2023-01-09T00:00:00</Date>
</someRequest>
```

I'm trying to fix

```
request.toString().Replace("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" ,"");
```

Is it possible to get the xml body as text?
Tried:

```
using (var reader = request.GetReaderAtBodyContents())
{
  query string var = reader.ReadContentAsString();
}

var body = request.getBody<string>();
```

If I implement the `IDispatchOperationSelector` interface. The method is called before `AfterReceiveRequest`. But there's also a `Message` parameter

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to extract `Number` and `Date` from xml and convert them to String.

Comment: I want to get all the xml as text to remove the extra `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, there is a signature in addition to these `Number` and `Date` fields.

Answer (score 0):

To read an xml file, you can use XmlDocument.InnerXml to get it :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("path to your file");
string xmlcontents = doc.InnerXml;
```

Or like this:

```
public string GetXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
    {

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        myxml.WriteTo(tx);

        string str = sw.ToString();// 
        return str;
    }
```

After getting it, then get rid of what you don't need.